# Changing font type of Jupyter Notebook output in VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I need help with changing the font of output in Jupyter Notebook. Sometime ago VSCode was updated and I saw the output font was changed from Consolas to Segoe UI. How can I revert this back?

Comment: Did you find a solution? All of a sudden also the Jupyter output on my VSC 1.73.1 does not respect che font I chose (only the output, not the code in the cells).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like this is the fault of the new renderer of version 1.65 ([link](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_65#_builtin-output-renderers-update)).

One work around is to go back to 1.64.2. The Jupyter extension need to be downgraded as well.

Comment: You were right, it is fixed right now. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Press `command` + `shift`+ `p` and then VScode bar will open add `>` and search "Open settings(UI)"

For quick:
directly type "font" in "search setting" and scroll down to see the "Font Family" for editor and there you can add your desired font family.

Comment: This allows to change to font size but not the font itself.

Comment: Hmm... didn't work it is still Segoe UI. Here is a screenshot of what I am talking about
https://i.imgur.com/HgWIDJu.png

Comment: If it doesn't take effect , can you upload your settings as pictures？

Answer (score 1):

Just insert at the beginig of your code

```
# Fix for Visual Studio Code
from IPython.core.display import HTML
HTML(r"""
<style>
    * {
        #color: red;
        #font-family: ‘Cascadia Code PL’;#,‘Courier New’, Courier, monospace; 
        font-family: ‘Courier New’, Courier, monospace; 
        font-size: 10px !important;
        line-height: 1.1 !important;
    }
    .output-plaintext, .output-stream, .output {
        font-family: ‘Courier New’, Courier, monospace; # Any monospaced font should work
        line-height: 1.3 !important;
        font-size: 12px !important;
    }
</style>
""")
```

Comment: This only works for Python notebooks, but not for e.g. Julia notebooks.